# Why can't I use realloc on arrays of defined size in C?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, realloc

I have a very basic question on memory allocation in C.
If I write:

```
int* test;
test = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
test[0] = 1;
test[1] = 2;
test[2] = 3;
test[3] = 4;
test[4] = 5;

test = realloc(test, 6 * sizeof(int));
```

I am able to use realloc. If I define test as:

```
int test[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

I am not able call *realloc* on it.

What is the lower level difference between these statements?
Can I somehow realloc on test[5]?
How do I free test[5]?

I am not sure where to look for an answer, if you could link a resource, I would be thankful.

Comment: Because `realloc` can only work with dynamically allocated memory. The second one is not (it is either static, or automatic - depending on context)

Comment: Because arrays are not pointers.

Comment: arrays have fixed position.. realloc gives you a pointer which may point to a different address

Comment: "How do I free test[5]?"  You don't.  You didn't allocate it, so you can't free it.  The compiler allocated it, and compiler-allocated memory is never freed.

Comment: One exception is to use a flexible array member as the last member in a `struct`. Memory is allocated for the struct, to include the required array length.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks, that's really the core of my question. I am technically able to obtain a pointer to an array like test[5], I expected it to behave the same.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, that's a useful piece of information

Comment: @AntonHinneck You are absolutely allowed to obtain a pointer to the beginning of array `test`, and in many respects it *does* behave exactly the same -- in particular, the pointer can be thought of as behaving almost exactly like the array.  What such a pointer is *not* like, though, is a pointer obtained from `malloc`.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thank you once more for the detailed comments. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `realloc()` to `int test[5]` because this `test` is not a pointer allocated via memory management functions (like `malloc()`) nor `NULL`.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.22.3.5 The realloc function:

> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the
> specified size. Otherwise, if ptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory
> management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the free or
> realloc function, the behavior is undefined. If memory for the new object cannot be
> allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

You cannot do re-allocation of `int test[5]`. (At least there are no standard way, but I cannot say there are no extended compiler that supports that).

To free `int test[5]`, exit from the block in which that is declared if it is a local variable. Such variable has an *automatic storage duration* and it is freed on exiting from the block. If it is a global (or static local) variable, exit the process and the OS will free the memory used by the process.

Comment: Thanks, if I define test [5] in a function, the memory is freed if it returns?

Comment: @AntonHinneck Absolutely.  All variables declared inside functions (unless qualified by `static`) are automatically freed when the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size because the type of `test` in `int test[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};` is `int[5]`. Number `5` is a part of its type and objects in C cannot change type after creation.

In `int* test;`, the `test` is a pointer and it can point to a memory region of an arbitrary number of consecutive `int`s.

Comment: Thank you, this makes total sense.

Comment: The newly allocated part of the memory returned by `realloc()` is not initialized.